# Abstract Method error is thrown on Click of button

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, ant, jar

I am getting an issue on click of button. Abstract method error is thrown on the page. What causes can be there for the same, please comment if someone knows ?

Tried to analyze the configuration and found something. The build machine and target machine are different in our project.

- Build Machine: The code gets compiled and generates .war files
- Target Machine : The war files to be deployed and the application
  runs from that machine.

**The build machine has following details :**

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.6) (rhel-1.43.1.10.6.el6_2-i386)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

Tomcat 6 is installed.

**The target Machine has following details :**

```
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.4.0.el6_6-i386 u75-b13)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Tomcat7 is installed on Target Machine.

**install.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Installing Web GUI on [${1}]"
echo "Stopping tomcat...";
ssh root@${1} "/sbin/service tomcat stop"
echo "Copying the WAR file..."
scp admin.war root@${1}:/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/
echo "Deploying and restarting tomcat..."
ssh root@${1} "rm -rf /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/admin;unzip -o -q /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/admin.war -d /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/admin;/sbin/service tomcat start"
echo "System should be up soon."
```

Abstract method Thrown :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:396)
    com.console.jsp.editCDTemplate_jsp._jspService(editCDTemplate_jsp.java:167)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1056)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:261)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:388)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:316)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:231)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    com.console.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:16)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**Is it require to update the tomcat on build machine also ? Please comment if i am doing something wrong.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the javax.servlet jar file is too old, async support was introduced in servlet 3.0 specs: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isAsyncSupported()

If your code requires that, then yes, upgrade the tomcat version. There's a servlet version compatibility matrix on tomcat's site as well.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have upgraded the tomcat version to compile the code and added relevant methods in the class. And the problem gets resolved. Thanks for the solution. Added servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar to the build machine from tomcat 7 lib. As tomcat 7 supports servlet-api.jar version 3.0 and previous version i.e. tomcat6 supports servlet-api.jar version 2.5. It has more methods added in next version.